# How to set total length of TCP option in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

I'm trying to add a new TCP option inside Linux kernel. However, I find that my new option cannot coexist with other options because there are no enough spaces in the option field for it. I get the warning from wireshark as "option goes past end of options".

So I'm wondering how I can extend the length of the whole TCP option field?

In `tcp_parse_options()` of `tcp_input.c`, I find such statement:
`int length = (th->doff * 4) - sizeof(struct tcphdr);`
And the while loop to parse options starts with `while (length > 0)`. However, no matter how I increase the value of `th->doff` in `tcp_make_synack()` of `tcp_output.c`, the problem remains. I also suspect this is because I add the option in SYN pakcet while this function is for SYN-ACK. But I cannot find similar functions such as `tcp_make_synack()`....

Does anyone have any insights of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does Wireshark perhaps hardcode the maximum number of options?

Comment: The data offset `th->doff` is a 4-bit number in the TCP header. The minimum value is 5 (no options) and the maximum value is 15. So you can only have 40 bytes of options.

Comment: @orlp Maybe not because my new option displays incompletely. But it's still recognized as an option.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! So do you know whether it is possible to change this limitation? In other words, where did the kernel set the min/max value for `th->doff`?

Comment: The max value for th->doff is not set by the kernel. The TCP protocol only has 4 bits to use in the TCP header. It is not possible to set increase the size of options and still use TCP.